# Why are universal families useful?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, universal-property, moduli-space

I recently started to read about moduli spaces. The best one can probably hope for, seems to be a fine moduli space and that is a moduli space that carries a universal family. In other words, the corresponding moduli functor is represented by a scheme. These are quite abstract notions but I think, I'm fine with the definitions.

One point that I didn't really get is what these families are really good for. For example, take the Grassmannian. It is a fine moduli space and carries the universal family $$U=\{(V,p)\in Gr(k,n)\times \mathbb P^n\mid p\in V\}$$ and we have natural projections $p: U\to Gr(k,n)$ and $q:U\to \mathbb P^n$. $p$ gives $U$ the structure of an algebraic bundle over the Grassmannian and this bundle is the tautological one (i.e. the fibre over a point is the subscheme parameterised by this point).

In *3264 and all that* by Eisenbud and Harris, they compute the tangent sheaf of the Grassmannian from this which is fair enough an application of the existence of an universal family but still seems to involve other things that are special to Grassmannians.

In general, it is not clear to me, why such a family is useful. Where does it make our lifes simpler? Are there standard arguments using the existence of universal families?

Comment: Since we don't typically have any way of getting our hands on moduli spaces with equations or other usual methods of studying varieties, the universal family allows us to define subvarieties via universal property. For example, if I write down a family of curves parametrized by $X$, the curves "pick out" fibers of the universal family so that I get a map $X \to \mathcal M_g$ (I'm really working on the stack here since I've specialized to moduli of curves)....

Comment: ...Divisors are typically defined in terms of some geometric condition on curves, and we compute intersection numbers by counting curves in a family satisfying that condition.

We also use the universal family to help define certain divisors in the first place. On every fiber of the universal family we have the canonical bundle $\omega_C$, and these bundles fit together into the relative dualizing sheaf $\omega_{\mathcal C/\mathcal M_g}$ on the universal family. By playing various games with Chern classes and pushforwards, we obtain divisor classes (and higher cohomology classes) on moduli.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. So if I understand you correctly, one of the main points is that we have an interpretation of open subsets of the moduli space as flat (?) family of objects being parameterised by the moduli space, correct?

Comment: So lets assume that I understood that correctly. If we are given any map $M_1\to M_2$ between fine moduli spaces, do things like showing maps to be morphisms then just reduce to checking that flat families map to flat families?

Comment: Yes, a flat family over a scheme isomorphic to that open subset. Your question about maps is essentially correct; you want to show that an arbitrary flat family of type 1 can be transformed uniquely into a flat family of type 2. In one of my advisor's papers (http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/mmpkontsevich.pdf) you can see this in action, where a result about a fixed curve is proved in Lemma 3.10, and then globalized to a result about an arbitrary flat family in Proposition 3.11.